# What is an inverse phrase for “topping-off”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

I’m looking for a term or phrase that is the inverse equivalent to the action of “topping-off”, like a gas tank, but meaning “to completely empty.”  Not a steady state (empty, depleted), but more a phrase implying readiness.

Example: If going for a long drive and you want to tell your girls to go to the bathroom first (even if they don’t have to.)

Something that means exactly the inverse of “topping-off”.

Comment: One of the problems is that _topping (off)_ can mean **either** to add a top (provisional) **or** to remove a top (privative). E.g, _They're topping off the trees by the garage today_ vs They're topping off the gas tank by the garage today_.

Comment: This may simply be a regionalism, but do you "top-off" or "top-up" a fuel reservoir when you add a small amount? Topping-off is also an alternative for "topping-out" a building when the final roof beam is added. Any antonym would relate to demolition.

Comment: On a side note, a potentially clearer alternative to "topping-off" might be "brimming up" (see: "brim" as a verb)[https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=brim&tbs=dfn:1]. I believe this is generally understood amongst most or all of the English dialects universally.

Comment: <i>"Brimming up"\</i>?  This reminds me of the great Guinness pour mantra: Make it just <b>“proud of the rim”</b> (aka surface tension - aka convex meniscus.)  Which reminds me of Ireland’s patron saint of arch enemies: Cromwell, and his maxim (here an antonym for top-off) “Keep your powder dry.”  (It is after all a ..powder room.)  Or perhaps “Keep your knickers dry.”  I digress.

Comment: How come your HTML tags work and mine don't? ^

Comment: @Alexander Sample size of one here, but I'd say that you'd get a lot of half-puzzled looks from Aus-eng speakers.

Comment: @ipso HTML doesn't work in comments (although it does in answers). You must use Markdown `*italic*` and `**bold**` for *italic* and **bold**. Entities don't work either, so you can't add an apostrophe with &rsquo;.

Comment: 'Completely empty' **is** surely the best answer. As you indicate, it can be used verbally (as well as adjectivally). Though it _would_ sound a little strange in the bathroom scenario. But then so would 'topping up / off' if you were preparing the girls for a long drive without eateries.

Comment: @tanantish - Wouldn't be the first time I've gotten that look from someone! :) I'm most familiar with British & American English & I was thinking this was the same Down Under as well, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think *drain* would work, from OED –

> drain, n
>
> The act of draining or drawing off;
>
> That which is drained or drawn off;

Comment: Drain.  ?  Hmm.

Squeeze dry (a wash cloth, or toothpaste)
Last drop (lemon, or a glass of water)
“Drain out“
“Drain off“
“Drain empty“
“Drain it“
“Drain it dry“

 “Drain it girls, drain it dry!  We’re headin’ for San Diego!”

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of *topping-off* should logically be *bottoming-out*.

And is.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest ***run dry***, as in:

> I ran the tank dry, and had to walk more than a mile to the gas station.

(This might not work for the bladder example in your question, but it could work for other contexts, such as wells or fuel tanks. That's the expression used in Steps 3 & 4 of [these winterizing instructions](http://www.ehow.com/how_7603861_winterize-inboard-outboard.html).)

Comment: You obviously understood his bladder example – I didn't!

Comment: @spiceyokooko: insofar as bladders go, I think _drain_ is a better fit than _run dry_, but I'd probably just use _empty_ for that context. :^)

Comment: I don't think his example was a particularly good one to demonstrate the word he was looking for. *Run dry* is perfect in the context of the reverse of topping up.

Comment: @spicey: While we're on the topic, I'll just mention this: usually, it's better to have the bladder drained or run dry (particularly before a long trip). However, there are some [exceptions](http://www.ivillage.com/ultrasound-do-you-need-full-bladder-ultrasound/6-n-138632) where it's better to be topped up.

Comment: Especially on New Years Eve :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you stated:

> *"Not a steady state (empty, depleted), but more a phrase implying readiness."*

I think that `empty` would still be valid if used as a verb.

Using your example of *`"If going for a long drive and you want to tell your girls to go to the bathroom first (even if they don’t have to.)"`*, you could say something along the lines of *`"Make sure to empty your bladders before we leave."`*, thus implying the necessary action.

Comment: “Empty your bladders” is exacting, I’ll give you that.  Perhaps a bit ..dry.  (“Daddy – what’s a bladder?”) :)

Answer (score 0):

*Drain the dregs*, to build off of @spicyokooko.

Comment: Always include some context and cite references.